# Probability that all the heads occur at the end of the sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

While reading my course handouts, I've found this question :

A fair coin is flipped n times. What’s the probability that all the heads occur
at the end of the sequence? (If no heads occur, then “all the heads are at the end of
the sequence” is vacuously true.)

I tried thinking of ways to solve it,but the best i could come up with was :

[image]

Where |H| is the number of heads.But the number of heads is not given in the problem.

What would be the correct way to solve it?

Comment: That would be correct for exactly $|H|$ number of heads, however the problem does not specify how many heads there must be.  Take this and range over all possible values of $|H|$ to complete the problem.

Comment: There are $2^n$ possible toss sequences (each equally probable)...for each $k\in \{0,\cdots, n\}$ there is exactly one that has precisely $k$ heads at the end preceded by all tails.  Therefore...

Comment: @August with $n$ flips, you have $0\leq |H|\leq n$

Comment: For future reference, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) teaches you how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ so you don't need to rely on images for typing math.

Comment: I'll learn how to use it,thank you @JMoravitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, you have to iterate over all possibilities of number of heads which will give following: $$P(E)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{n-k}}\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{n+1}{2^n}$$

Comment: Don't different number of heads appearing have different probabilities? Like for $n=100$, $50$ heads appearing is certainly more common than $1$ head appearing.

Comment: Since the coin is unbiased probabilities are same for getting any sequence of $n$ head and tails. For biased coin, yes the probabilities will be different. For the coin with probability p of getting head $P(E)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(1-p)^{n-k}p^k$.

Comment: @WillSherwood for a fair coin 50 heads appearing out of 100 flips **in any order** is more common than only one head appearing out of 100 flips **in any order**, however 50 tails followed by 50 heads is exactly as likely to occur as 99 tails followed by 1 head.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps easier to describe, remember that the possible sequences of results of a fair coin of the same length are each equally likely.

The "good" sequences where all heads (*if any occur*) are at the end of the sequence are those sequences:

$$hhh\dots hh,~~thh\dots hh,~~tth\dots hh,~~ ttt\dots hh,~~ttt\dots th,~~ttt\dots tt$$

We can see that there are exactly $n+1$ different "good" sequences.  (*If you have a hard time seeing this, recognize that we can describe each sequence as a sequence of $n$ stars and one bar, the stars to the left of the bar represents the tails and to the right of the bar represents heads.  E.g. $\star\star\mid\star\star\star$ represents the sequence $tthhh$.  The number of sequences of $n$ stars and one bar is $n+1$*)

As there are $2^n$ possible sequences of $n$ coinflips and each of them are equally likely, we see that the probability is then the ratio of "good" outcomes over the total number of outcomes in the sample space, i.e.

$$\frac{n+1}{2^n}$$

---

Your method is also the start to a correct solution, noting that you need to iterate over all possible values for $|H|$, and generalizes more nicely to the problem where the coin is not fair.

Letting $p$ be the probability of a head and $(1-p)$ be the probability of a tail, we have the probability all heads appear at the end to be

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n(1-p)^kp^{n-k}$$